# Making somewhat a history feed like console.log does

Tags: javascript, developer-console

first time asking on Stack, could someone please help me figuring out how could I output the eval in a visual feedback like the dev console does, something like a history feed.

```js
(function init() {
var btn = document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
            var iostore = document.getElementById("io");
            var history = document.getElementById("history");
            var result = eval(iostore.value);
            console.log(result);
            iostore.value = result; 
};


})();
```

```css
body, html{width:100%;height:100%;margin: 0px auto;background-color:#EEE;}
#io{background-color:aqua;width:auto;height:auto;border:0;outline:none;font-size:1.5em;}
button{border:0;border-radius: 5px;background-color:#999;font-size:1.7em;}#history{resize: none;background-color:#EEE;border:0;outline:none;cursor:default;color:black;opacity:0.7;}#creation{background-color:aqua;width:auto;height:auto;border:0;outline:none;font-size:1.5em;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="interfacecontainer">
<input type="text" id="io">  
<button id="btn">run</button><br>
<textarea id="history"></textarea> 
<div id="creation"></div>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

[What i mean (browser print-screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR19L.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just update the value inside the textarea. `history.textContent += result` or `history.innerHTML += result`. Also eval is evil, never use it unless you really need it. And this is a case where it's completely unneeded. `iostore.value` should automatically give you the text inside the input, no need to eval it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read up on exactly what [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) does to make sure its what you want. Then because it's trying to evaluate an expression I'd put it in a `try catch` where if there is an exception you can output the exception. Then append the textarea with the result or the exception. I've also resized your textarea a bit so you can see a few more results.

```js
(function init() {
var btn = document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
            var iostore = document.getElementById("io");
            var history = document.getElementById("history");
try {
var result =eval(iostore.value);
history.value += result+"\n";
} catch (e) {
    iostore.value=e.message;
history.value += e.message+"\n";

} 
};


})();
```

```css
body, html{width:100%;height:100%;margin: 0px auto;background-color:#EEE;}
#io{background-color:aqua;width:auto;height:auto;border:0;outline:none;font-size:1.5em;}
button{border:0;border-radius: 5px;background-color:#999;font-size:1.7em;}#history{resize: none;background-color:#EEE;border:0;outline:none;cursor:default;color:black;opacity:0.7;height:50px}#creation{background-color:aqua;width:auto;height:auto;border:0;outline:none;font-size:1.5em;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="interfacecontainer">
<input type="text" id="io">  
<button id="btn">run</button><br>
<textarea id="history"></textarea> 
<div id="creation"></div>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```